# Integration-Can anyone give the technique t0 integrate this type of problems?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$
\int_0^\pi \sqrt{4\sin^2x-4\sin x+1}\;dx
$$

Can anyone give the technique t0 integrate this type of problems?

I didn't do this type of problems earlier.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** $4x^2-4x+1=(2x-1)^2$. Use this idea in your integral.

Comment: The problem arise after that.

Comment: As I hinted and others point out: $\int \sqrt{4\sin^2 x-4\sin x+1}\;dx=\int \sqrt{(2\sin x-1)^2}\;dx=\int 2\sin x -1\;dx$. If you are having troubles with $\int 2\sin x -1\;dx$, you should think what function to I differentiate to get $\sin x$, then multiply by $2$. What function do I differentiate to get $-1$?, add these up then just plug in your upper and lower limits to find the answer.

Comment: There is a mod,i.e.|2sinx-1|.

Comment: You've made an error I see the OP has noticed: $$\sqrt{(2\sin x-1)^2}=\pm (2\sin x -1)$$ As I've shown in my post, we have to split up the region of integration in order to use $\pm (2\sin x - 1)$, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Either notice that your root arguement is $(2\sin x-1)^2$ or substitute $u=\sin x$ and continue from there.

Comment: The problem arise after that.

Answer (score 1):

The radicand is a quadratic is $\sin x$. Put $\sin x = t$ and factor to get $$4t^2 - 4t + 1 = (2t-1)^2 = (2\sin x - 1)^2$$

Hint: You'll need to remember that $$\sqrt{(2\sin x - 1)^2} = \pm (2\sin x - 1)$$ Split the integral into three, in order to correctly order the integrand. $$\int_0^{\pi/6} (1-2\sin x)\,dx + \int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6} (2\sin x - 1)\,dx = \int_{5\pi/6}^\pi (1 - 2\sin x)\,dx$$

Recall that $\sin x \le \frac12 \in [0. \pi/6], [5\pi/6, \pi]$, and $\sin x \geq \frac 12 \in [\pi/6, 5\pi/6]$

Comment: The problem arise after that.

Comment: @user146181, can you tell us what the problem is?

Comment: @Kurtbusch How do u get the pi/6?

Comment: It turns out I answered this fully on your duplicated post. You failed to follow up with me on both my posts.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @user146181 what pi/6? I never submitted an answer...

Comment: @Kurtbusch I think the op may have been answering your question: "can you tell us what the problem is?"